# postgreSQL: Separate functions on columns with WHERE .. LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Beginner question**

I have 3 columns:

- id
- event
- time

I'm trying to, for each id, in one column take the max of the time if event = 'eventa' and take the min of each time if event = 'eventb'.

So far, I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id), MIN(time) as first_assigned,
FROM customer_journey_events 
WHERE event_type LIKE 'eventa'
GROUP BY account_id
```

This yields a table format of:

| id | first_assigned |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 2021-03-17T20:41:50.469Z |
| id2 | 2021-03-22T08:39:13.303Z |

**etc...**

How could I **add an additional column that takes the maximum of the time when the event type = 'eventb'**? My attempts to solve this aren't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.  That looks like:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(time) FILTER (WHERE event = 'eventa'),
       MAX(time) FILTER (WHERE event = 'eventb')
FROM customer_journey_events 
GROUP BY id
```